# I have added a local storage function but it doesnt seem to work on my Scheduler i have created and i cant figure out why

Tags: javascript, java, html, local-storage, momentjs

So i have created a work day scheduler for a project im working on, iv managed to added the colour blocking for times of the day no problem, but im having real issues getting the local storage to work for the text input (eg: when i type a sentence into a time block i want it to save and then persist on reload of the page) Any help with what i have done wrong or any suggestions on how to make this work would be appreciated.

```js
const clock = document.getElementById("clock");
setInterval(() => {
    const now = moment();
    const readable = now.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    clock.textContent = readable;

}, 1000);

// $(document).ready(function () {

    var saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".saveBtn");
    
    saveBtn.forEach(function(node) {
       
        node.addEventListener("click", function() {
           
            var description = $(this).siblings(".description").val();
            
            var time = $(this).parent().attr("id");
            
            localStorage.setItem(time, description);
    
        })
    });
    
    
    $("#hour1 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour1"));
    $("#hour2 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour2"));
    $("#hour3 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour3"));
    $("#hour4 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour4"));
    $("#hour5 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour5"));
    $("#hour6 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour6"));
    $("#hour7 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour7"));
    $("#hour8 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour8"));
    $("#hour9 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour9"));
    $("#hour10 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour10"));
    

    var elements = $(".time-block");
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();


    for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var t = parseInt(elements[i].getAttribute("data-hour"));

        if (h < t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        } else if (h > t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        } else if (h === t) {
            elements[i].classList.add('present');
            elements[i].classList.remove('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
        } else if (h > 16 && h < 9) {
            elements[i].classList.add('future');
            elements[i].classList.remove('past');
            elements[i].classList.remove('present');
        }
    }
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1;
}

textarea {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  color: #000000;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.jumbotron {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}

.description {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}

.time-block {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.row {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  height: 80px;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

.hour {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 1px dashed #000000;
}

.past {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  color: white;
}

.present {
  background-color: #ff6961;
  color: white;
}

.future {
  background-color: #77dd77;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #06aed5;
  color: white;
}

.saveBtn i:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css" />
  <title>Work Day Scheduler</title>
  <header class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-3">Work Day Scheduler</h1>
    <p class="lead">A simple calendar app for scheduling your work day</p>
    <p id="currentDay" class="lead"></p>
    <div id="clock"></div>
  </header>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Timeblocks go here -->

  <div id ="hour-1" data-hour="8" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-1 hour">
      8AM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="8AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-2" data-hour="9" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      9AM
    </div>
    <textarea id="9AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-3" data-hour="10" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      10AM
    </div>
    <textarea id="10AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-4" data-hour="11" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      11AM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="11AM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-5" data-hour="12" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      12PM
    </div>
    <textarea id ="12PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-6" data-hour="13" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      1PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="1PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-7" data-hour="14" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      2PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="2PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-8" data-hour="15" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      3PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="3PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-9" data-hour="16" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      4PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="4PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div id ="hour-10" data-hour="17" class = "row time-block">
    <div class="col-md-1 hour">
      5PM
    </div>
    <textarea id="5PM" class="col-md-10 description">
    </textarea>
    <button class="col-1 saveBtn btn"><i class="fas fa-save"></i></button>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: well, it won't work in a snippet - what errors do you get where it could work?

Comment: What values you get when you console.log(time, description) in your save function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this block :

```
var saveBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".saveBtn");
    
 saveBtn.forEach(function(node) {
       
   node.addEventListener("click", function() {
           
      var description = $(this).siblings(".description").val();
            
      var time = $(this).parent().attr("id");
            
      localStorage.setItem(time, description);
    
   })
});
```

you are storing in local storage with a key which is the `id` of the button's parent which is `hour-1`...`hour-2`.. etc

and then here :

```
 $("#hour1 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour1"));
```

You are trying to set the value of the `.description` of `#hour1` **which does not exist** from a local storage key **which does not exist** (`hour1`)

So in order to fix this you can just select the correct elements `$("#hour-1 .description").val(localStorage.getItem("hour-1"));`

Always do some debugging yourself before stepping and asking for help,for example if you'd just `console.log(time, description)` right after you set it to local storage it would give the cause of error right away

Comment: Thanks so much for the response, im still a bit confused how would i fix this?